# PHP Ajax adjustments

Tags: php

My Website is Structured like:

`index.php` which includes a `router.php` and `router.php` calls required `controller`.

for example if I call a list page like `http://example.com/index.php?list`

the `router` will call the `list controller`. And `list controller` includes `header, pagination, search_form, list_items,footer views`

At the moment every time I click on the page number in Pagination list the complete page will be reloaded and
all initilization that are in `index.php` and in l`ist_controller` will be loaded.

But now I want to change this process. I only have to reload the `list_items` view when clicking on page number.
Now problem is the variable, constants, and class initilization that were done in `index` and in `list_controller` are missing if i call the `list_item view` directly.

I don't want to change the complete Struct of the website. Is there a way to make all the variables, constants and object available for such an ajax request? As in coldfusion if a page is requested we have a possiblility to initilize the request variables before the request actually runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check bootstrap file and configuration of codeigniter

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/config.html